# Setting a border-radius property when using Transify

Tags: jquery, css

I am using [Transify](http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/transify-a-jquery-plugin-to-easily-apply-transparency-opacity-to-an-elements-background) to make a div semi-transparent, but also want to add rounded edges.

When using Transify, the rounded edges only appear until the page is fully loaded.

CSS:

```
.grid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 320px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid" id="content">
... irrelevant content ...
</div>

<script>
    $('#content').transify({opacityOrig:.8,percentWidth:'100%'});
</script>
```

How do I achieve both?

Answer (score 1):

Transify does not natively respect the border-radius property defined in css.

This includes using other methods, such as [curvyCorners](https://www.appnovation.com/resources/code-snippet/curvycorners-js-plugin), or `jQuery.css()`.

This can be fixed through a simple edit of the Transify script.

```
transBG.css({
...
backgroundRepeat:$this.css('backgroundRepeat'),
borderRadius:$this.css('borderRadius'), <- add this line
borderTopColor:$this.css('borderTopColor'),
...
```

When attempting to post this on the Transify website, comments have been disabled via a redirect to the "we don't allow comment spam here" page and development appears to have ceased.